# Fix the size of all images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 to create a page of user profiles and display them in rows of 6 (on a big screen).
The problem is that the profiles have images of different sizes and I'm trying to figure out how to force them to all be the same height and width with out changing the aspect ratio( cropping the image is fine).
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/ajpofdzr/4/)

This is what I have so far:

```
   <div class="col-sm-2 thumb">
                  <div class="card" border="1px;" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <figure class="member">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Annex_-_Stewart%2C_James_%28Call_Northside_777%29_01.jpg/220px-Annex_-_Stewart%2C_James_%28Call_Northside_777%29_01.jpg" height="150" alt="Card image cap">
  <figcaption class="member-details bordered no-top-border">
                      <h3>
                        Jimmy Stewart
                        </h3>
                        <p>Actor</p>

                    </figcaption>
                     </figure>
</div>

                </div><!-- /.col -->
```

Comment: To get all images the same size I create a div with a fixed height and/or width and then set the image as a background image. Using background-size:cover usually fixes any issues of white gaps.

Comment: Lots of different ways to do this so it really depends on your needs! I would go with Ginger Squirrel solution of using background images ... if the images are going to end up being dynamic this may be more or a problem - https://jsfiddle.net/srdo03oj/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with [`object-fit: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit?v=example), but this feature [is not supported by IE/Edge](http://caniuse.com/object-fit/embed/agents=desktop). If you need IE support - you can try to use [`background-size: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?v=control), which is at least [supported by the latest IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts).

Here is a working [jsfiddle with both solutions](https://jsfiddle.net/dabemzLo/5/).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `overflow: hidden` style. Here is an example how you image would stay in the div element:

https://jsfiddle.net/ajpofdzr/6/

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful: [Centre crop thumbnails with CSS](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/)

```
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.thumbnail img.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```